# Autoscroll a JScrollpane when dragging an object

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, autoscroll, scrollpane

I have created a appointment calendar which essentially is a JPanel which contains other movable and resizable JPanels all surrounded by a JScrollpane, this all works well and I am able to scroll around the JPanel using the scrollbars correctly. I close to finishing my application but would like to achieve one more thing.

What I would like to do is when a user is moving the appointment (JPanel), when you reach the edge of scrollpane it automatically will scroll at a desired speed. I am confused which existing method or class can do this (if there is one) or if anyone knows of a jar library available out there that will suit my needs?

Is that being lazy? Yeah probably, I guess I should code it myself, if you do agree could someone suggest where I would start? I'm still learning Java and I might need a gentle nudge to keep my code clean and tidy.

If I can provide anymore detail to help with an answer, let me know.

Comment: thanks @GuillaumePolet, I've tried adding this to both the scrollpane and panel, but it doesn't work. It may well be that something I've done is conflicting with this method. I'll look at adding the code I'm working on. It's going to take time to trim it down, it's massive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it's actually not much complicated. You need to call `setAutoscroll(true);` on your "scrollable" component and add a `MouseMotionListener` which invokes `scrollRectToVisible`.

Here is a small example code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestImageResize {

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestImageResize.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                "http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/19/5/islands-paradise-maldive-nature-background-image-landscape-194469.jpg"));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
        panel.add(label);
        MouseMotionListener doScrollRectToVisible = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
                ((JPanel) e.getSource()).scrollRectToVisible(r);
            }
        };
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(doScrollRectToVisible);

        panel.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() / 2, frame.getHeight() / 2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestImageResize().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent the example works how I want it to. I shall apply it to my code and report back. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: OK, it works when I drag on the main panel, but not when I move another jpanel that is on top.

Comment: I've added the listener to the individual appointments, but when I drag it scrolls all the way to the top. I've added in below what I changed: `MouseMotionListener doScrollRectToVisible = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  Rectangle r = new Rectangle(mainPanel.getX(), mainPanel.getY(), 1, 1);
  mainPanel.scrollRectToVisible(r);
 }
};
appPanel.addMouseMotionListener(doScrollRectToVisible);` Eeeek! How do you enter a newline in comments? Sorry!

Comment: @JoeChamberlain Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your problem. This `new Rectangle(mainPanel.getX(), mainPanel.getY(), 1, 1);` can only be wrong. mainPanel.getX() will always be 0